# Depending values in an instance of a class

Tags: python, class, random, instance

I am new to python and stuck with a simple problem:
Here is an example code:

```
import random
class shirt:
    def __init__(self, color, size, size_description):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.size_description = size_description

def randomshirtsize():
    randomshirtsize_ch = (
        's',
        'm',
        'l'
    )
    return random.choice(randomshirtsize_ch)

def randomshirtdescription():
    if randomshirtsize() == 's':
        return 'small'
    elif randomshirtsize() == 'm':
        return 'medium'
    elif randomshirtsize() == 'l':
        return 'large'
    else:
        return 'Error! No valid size found'

shirt1 = shirt('blue', randomshirtsize(), randomshirtdescription())

print('Your shirt is size ' + shirt1.size + '. In other words ' + shirt1.size_description)
```

In theory, randomshirtdescription() should match the output of randomshirtsize(), but it is totally random. Can anyone help me out?
I also want to stay with my classes/instances approach to this, because my main code is much larger and depends on classes and instances.

EDIT: This is the new code with the approach from Mr Alihoseiny but i still cant get it to work.

```
import random
class shirt:
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.size_description = get_size_description()

    def get_size_description(self):
        if  self.size == 's':
            return 'small'
        elif self.size == 'm':
            return 'medium'
        elif self.size == 'l':
            return 'large'
        else:
            return 'Error! No valid size found'


def randomshirtsize():
    randomshirtsize_ch = (
        's',
        'm',
        'l'
    )
    return random.choice(randomshirtsize_ch)


shirt1 = shirt('blue', randomshirtsize())

print('Your shirt is size ' + shirt1.size + '. In other words ' + shirt1.size_description)
```

When i run it i get following error:
NameError: name 'get_size_description' is not defined

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `randomshirtsize()` in your `shirt` class call, but then you're calling it *again* in `randomshirtdescription`. In fact, you call it three times in that function. What you're looking to do is run `randomshirtsize()` once, and pass those results into `randomshirtdescription()` so that the results are static and not being recalculated every time you're trying to compare the value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @brittenb Make that an answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: @dfundako Eh, I'd rather let lower-rep people answer and get the votes, like below.

Comment: @ brittenb Thanks for the quick reply. You are right, it makes sense. Can you show me a way to pass the result from one function to the other? I tried the approach from Mr Alihoseiny down below, but it didn´t work out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randomshirtsize` creates a random output each time it calls, so when you want to use it in the `randomshirtdescription`, you should store the value of it to a local variable and use the value of that variable in `if` statements. like this:

```
def randomshirtdescription():
    random_size = randomshirtsize()
    if  random_size == 's':
        return 'small'
    elif random_size == 'm':
        return 'medium'
    elif random_size == 'l':
        return 'large'
    else:
        return 'Error! No valid size found'
```

**Edit**

If you make mentioned change, your functions work correctly, but their behavior is not correct when using with your class. I think it is better to make a change in them.

I think it is better to change the `randomshirtdescription` function to a function that returns the description of a given shirt size. Something like this:

```
def shirtdescription(shirt_size):
    if  shirt_size == 's':
        return 'small'
    elif shirt_size == 'm':
        return 'medium'
    elif shirt_size == 'l':
        return 'large'
    else:
        return 'Error! No valid size found'
```

Now you can get expected results from your code with calling your class and functions if following way:

```
random_size = randomshirtsize()
shirt1 = shirt('blue', random_size, randomshirtdescription(random_size))
```

But still, this solution is not object-oriented. I think it is better to convert this new `shirtdescription` into a method of your `shirt` class.

I think a better class will be something like this:

```
class shirt:

    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.size_description = self.get_size_description()

    def get_size_description(self):
        if  self.size == 's':
            return 'small'
        elif self.size == 'm':
            return 'medium'
        elif self.size == 'l':
            return 'large'
        else:
            return 'Error! No valid size found'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately even with your solution, the output is still random. Do i have to change anything else in my code?

Comment: Now I found that there was a mistake in my solution and I removed () after random_size if `elif`s. Made that change to your code, if still something is wrong, please add some example of wrong output and expected one to your question.

Comment: Your changes make sense, still it outputs random results like: "Your shirt is size l. In other words small". I think it is, because we call randomshirtsize() again in randomshirtdescription() and therefor getting a new random result.

Comment: I've added more ways to do what you want. hoping this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the long reply, really appreciate your solutions. One final question: how would my shirt1 instance look like with your second solution? ' shirt1 = shirt('blue', randomshirtsize(), ??? ) '

Comment: Your welcome. In second solution you only need to pass two parameters to the constructor of the class. `color` and the `size`. `size_description` will generate inside the class.

Comment: I am yet again stuck. I edited my post above to show my new code. Maybe you can help me out one more time.

Comment: I saw that. Please add change `self.size_description = get_size_description()` to `self.size_description = self.get_size_description()`. Lake of `self` before method name for python interpreter means that `get_size_description` is a function outside of the class scope.

Comment: Finally! Thank you a lot, i got it.